# Websocket server on subdomain only

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to have a websocket server on a subdomain so the client would point to something like 'ws://ws.mydomain.com'.

I'm using the subdomain module to handle normal get requests to subdomains but not sure how to consolidate the two. Any ideas on how I can approach this?

The WebSocketServer can take a server object, but can't figure it out.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var express = require('express');
var subdomain = require('subdomain');
var app = express();
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8081, server: http.Server});
app.use(subdomain({ base: 'mydomain.com', removeWWW: true}));

wss.on('connection', function(ws){
  console.log('a connection!');
});

app.get('/subdomain/unrelatedsub', function(req, res){
  res.send("hello unrelated subdomain page");
});

app.listen(80);
```

[Link to WS documentation](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md)

Answer (score 0):

[From the web socket protocol:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455%22Web%20Socket%20protocol%22)

> The WebSocket Protocol attempts to address the    goals of existing
> bidirectional HTTP technologies in the context of    the existing HTTP
> infrastructure; as such, it is designed to work    over HTTP ports 80
> and 443 as well as to support HTTP proxies and    intermediaries, even
> if this implies some complexity specific to the    current
> environment.

Express 3 exposes the app as a request handler, you must instantiate a `http.Server` first which you can pass the express app into, and then you setup your sockets, as the ws:// protocal can share the HTTP port you listen on, just as wss:// would share the HTTPS port.

Try something closer to this, I will test when get a chance if you haven't responded:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http')
var app = express();

app.use(subdomain({ base: 'mydomain.com', removeWWW: true}));

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});

wss.on('connection', function(ws){
  console.log('a connection!');
});

app.get('/subdomain/unrelatedsub', function(req, res){
  res.send("hello unrelated subdomain page");
});
```

Comment: Can't see a subdomain specific websocket server shown in your code example.

Comment: I based my code around your initial posting, but we `app.use(subdomain` then we create server by passing `'app'` to the `http.createServer` and then providing `server` for the `new WebSocketServer` constructor.

Comment: Didn't have any luck with this one. Decided to go with an nginx reverse proxy server on top of nodejs